# a non static member reference must be relative to a specific object

Tags: c++, mfc

I have been building a simple application which requires a separate thread to run some background code in a `while` loop. I have a text box which I want to send messages to from the code running in the separate thread however I am unable to.

A non static member reference must be relative to a specific object. From my understanding to run an additional thread it seems that I have to make the function `static`. However when I try and write a message to `m_Console` I see the error:

> A non static member reference must be relative to a specific object.

I tried initialising the object but it doesn't do anything.

```
CMFCApplication1Dlg  obj;
obj.m_Console = "Test"
```

- The code that uses a separate thread is:
  **`static UINT checkSomething(LPVOID pParam);`**
- The text box variable is:
  **`CString m_Console;`**

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedBtnAdd(){
m_Console = "Parser is now running..";
AfxBeginThread(checkSomething,"");
```

I have tried the suggestion:

```
UINT CMFCApplication1Dlg::checkSomething(LPVOID pParam){
    CMFCApplication1Dlg* pObject = (CMFCApplication1Dlg*)pParam;
    pObject->m_Console = "I am in thread";
```

But it throws an access violation error on: `pObject->m_Console = "I am in thread";`

> Exception thrown at 0x0FE90DBD (mfc140ud.dll) in MFCApplication1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFC.

Here is the code:

**MFCApplication1Dlg.cpp**

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedBtnAdd(){      


m_Console = "Something Parser is now running..";
AfxBeginThread(checkSomething,"");

CWnd* okbtn = GetDlgItem(IDC_BTN_ADD);
if (okbtn) {
    okbtn->EnableWindow(FALSE);
}

// without UpdateData() status area will _NOT_ be updated.
UpdateData(FALSE);}


INT CMFCApplication1Dlg::checkSomething(LPVOID pParam){

CMFCApplication1Dlg* pObject = (CMFCApplication1Dlg*)pParam;

pObject->m_Console = "I am in thread";
```

**MFCApplication1Dlg.h**

```
public:
afx_msg void OnBnClickedBtnAdd();
static int messenger();
static UINT checkSomething(LPVOID pParam);
CString m_Console;
```

**Textbox:**
IDC_Console

- **Category**: value
- **Access**: public
- **Control type**: LText
- **Name**: m_Console
- **Variable type**: CString

From reading everyone's comments, it seems as if this is something that I am not supposed to do in C++, question is then, what if I had a background task running a loop in in a separate thread which needed to update the status box on the UI? To me that seems a logical thing someone might wish to do but if I'm not supposed to do that then how would that be done? I am running the task in a separate thread because it uses a while loop and if I don't use a separate thread it just freezes the whole application.

Comment: You tag `mfc`. Do you use `Visual Studio 2019`?

Comment: yes that is right.

Comment: Ok, then the answer to "_From my understanding to run an additional thread it seems that I have to make the function static_" is **no**, your understanding is wrong.

Comment: The best way to demonstrate what you want to do is to make a [mcve]. And by that I mean one that people can copy and compile as-is.

Comment: As a general rule, you should not attempt to modify the UI from a thread other than the thread that created the UI, neither directly nor indirectly.

Comment: @IINspectable thanks,  if I were running a background task in a separate thread, how would I then pass that information onto the UI if I am not supposed to modify the UI from a separate thread? What if the background task is running a while loop that needs to update a status box on the UI?

Comment: It's very likely, that you do not need a dedicated thread. But if you really do you would typically update your state, and notify the UI (e.g. through posting a message, or signaling a synchronization object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deliver the object of CMFCApplication1Dlg as parameter for the Thread function.

e.g

```
UINT MyThreadProc( LPVOID pParam )
{
    CMFCApplication1Dlg * pObject = (CMFCApplication1Dlg *)pParam;

    pObject->m_Console = "I am in thread";
}

// .... .... ... 

AfxBeginThread(MyThreadProc, this);
```

I hope this answer will work for you.

Comment: I tried the code above but it throws an access violation exception.

Comment: @MrTea The ruthless casting you got involved in, as the `LPVOID` reinterpreted as a `CMFCApplication1Dlg*` may have something to do with it.

Comment: Hi Ted, any additional advice how to make it work? Just trying to update text in a box but it seems to be a bit of a challenge.

Comment: where did you call AfxBeginThread? can you debug and check the pObject is not null in the MyThreadFunc?

Comment: I call AfxBEginThread(checkSomething,"") in the void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedBtnAdd(){

Comment: @MrTea How could I advice on such a thing with the information given?

Comment: The second parameter of AfxBeginThread is "", and that can not be cascaded to CMFCApplication1Dlg*.
So you should call AfxBeginThread(checksomething, this)

Comment: ysk silver! Genius! Thanks that did it!

Comment: It works as long as its outside the while loop in the thread. When I try  pObject->m_Console = "I am in thread"; in the while loop the textbox won't update. Currently not sure why.

Comment: pObject->m_Console = "I am in thread";  this code will update nothing.
Instead use pObject->m_Console += "I am in thread";

Answer (score 0):

Changed

```
AfxBeginThread(checkSomething,""); to

AfxBeginThread(checkSomething,this);
```

as suggested by ysk silver, thanks!

I needed to add a Timer Function which I followed this article:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mfc/mfc_multithreading.htm

Once I did this, the UI box updates.

```
int currValue;int maxValue;BOOL stopNow;string output;


BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMFCApplication1Dlg, CDialogEx)
ON_WM_SYSCOMMAND()
ON_WM_PAINT()
ON_WM_QUERYDRAGICON()
ON_WM_ERASEBKGND()
ON_WM_CTLCOLOR()
ON_WM_TIMER()  //TIMER
ON_BN_CLICKED(IDC_BTN_ADD, &CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedBtnAdd)
```

END_MESSAGE_MAP()

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnTimer(UINT_PTR nIDEvent) {

CDialogEx::OnTimer(nIDEvent);
UpdateData(FALSE);}

void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedBtnAdd(){      
SetTimer(1234, 333, 0); // 3 times per second
m_Console = "Parser is now running..";
AfxBeginThread(checkSomething,this);
```

I then can change the text in the checkSomething method:

```
CMFCApplication1Dlg* pObject = (CMFCApplication1Dlg*)pParam;
output = "I am in thread";
pObject->messenger(output);
//OR
  pObject->m_Console = "I am in thread";
```

And the textbox updates!